# Is it possible to connect Github to Unfuddle to use powerful commit messages?

Tags: github, ticket-system, unfuddle

My team is using Github for code hosting and Unfuddle for ticketing. Is it possible to connect Github to Unfuddle so that we are able to update/close tickets from our commit messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is provided from the Unfuddle service hook offered in Github. You can find it in the admin section of your repository.

Answer (score 6):

As markdorison notes, there are service hooks in github enterprise to do this.

First, you need to make sure your github account has the permissions necessary to administer your repo. You need to be set up as a repository "owner."

Once you have those permissions, if you go to the overview page of your github hosted repository `/ORGANIZATION/REPOSITORY`, you will see a row of familiar tabs, with one new member at the far right:

Code  Network Pull Requests  Issues  Graphs  **Admin**

Click on admin, and you'll see a menu at the left of the admin page with a link to "Service Hooks."

Once you're on this page, scroll (far) down to find the "unfuddle" service hook.

Click on the Unfuddle service hook and a small form will open up in the upper right of your browser. Fill it out like so:

```
Subdomain: Your organization's unfuddle subdomain, ie ORG.unfuddle.com
Repo Id: The numeric Id of the github repository you are trying to connect to unfuddle.
Username: Your unfuddle user account name.
Password: Your unfuddle user account password.
_ HttpOnly (check if appropriate)
√ Active (set to active to use this service, uncheck to stop using it)
```

Then click the "update settings" submit button.

On completion, you will see a new button called "Test Hook." Click that to test the connection and make sure it is working.

Within a few minutes, you should start seeing commit history being reflected in Unfuddle's repository listings.

Pro Tip: Set up an `Unfuddle` account just for external services like github, and use this account instead of individual users accounts, for creating the service hookup.